# How to sync personal dictionary between devices (Google Keyboard)?

Tags: sync, keyboard, google

I also have installed Google Keyboard app on my tablet and have selected my main Google account as the sync account. The dictionary was initially empty but I have added some words. I also pressed "Sync now" after adding the words.

I have also installed the Google Keyboard app on my phone and just have also selected the same account as on the tablet and have pressed "Sync now". BUT the dictionary hasn't transferred to my phone.

Any ideas on how to make this will work? Thanks! :)

Comment: Make sure `Google Keyboard Sync` on. To find this option go to Settings >> Language & Input >> Google Keyboard >> Accounts and Privacy.

Comment: sync is enabled and as mentioned in original post, I have selected the same Google account on both devices.

Comment: @jan There's no "Accounts and Privacy" menu item in GBoard's settings. I went through the whole settings and didn't find anything related to syncing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you try the below troubleshooting steps:

1. Clear cache for Google Keyboard app (Go to Settings > Apps or Application Manager > ALL > Google Keyboard > Storage > Clear cache > OK).
2. [Clear cache data for the Google Play Store](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6332367) app.
3. Uninstall and reinstall the Google Keyboard updates. (Go to Settings > Apps or Application Manager > Google Keyboard > Uninstall Updates > OK).

If the above steps don't help, I'd suggest you contact our one-on-one support team using this **[link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6179357?hl=en#contact=1)** for better assistance.